# SQL выбрать число из диапазона двух дат

Tags: mysql, sql

Как можно выбрать число из диапазона двух дат DD.MM? Если, к примеру, столбец from будет 21.03, а столбец to будет 20.04, а нужно выбрать 15.04?

Comment: что за тип столбца у вас varchar, или это таки полноценная дата?. какое число надо выбрать из этого диапазона, произвольное?

Comment: @teran тип столбца varchar. Да, нужно выбрать произвольное

Comment: *тип столбца varchar* Придётся переворачивать в формат ММ.ДД - причём и значения полей, и выбираемую дату. Например, с помощью выражения `CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(datefield,'.',-1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(datefield,'.',1))`. Теперь можно использовать вульгарный BETWEEN...

Comment: @Akina а можно как-то без переворота? Если выбрать другой тип столбца, например

Comment: Лучше выбрать другой формат хранения. Если в данных только день и месяц, без года... хранить именно в показанном выше формате. И можно даже без разделителя. И даже в INT(4).